# Dynamically allocate a parameter for action when running a sequence

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, duration, skaction

I stumbled upon a problem and I can't find the answer for it. I am working with the SK template from Xcode to create an iOS game. I am a beginner, so bear with me.

Basically I have this code:

```
SKAction *releaseBubbles = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                                    [SKAction performSelector:@selector(createBubbleNode)onTarget:self],
                                                    [SKAction waitForDuration:speed]]];
[self runAction: [SKAction repeatAction:releaseBubbles
                                      count:300]];
```

which executes in

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
```

I change the level to my game in `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {` and when I change the level it should also change that speed parameter. Of course, this doesn't work because I believe that my action is starting when the scene is initialised and I never get to switch the parameter.

What I need to do is populate the screen continuously with bubbles appearing at a certain pace (relative to the level).

I really have no clue how to fix this, because it seems to me like I need to stop and restart the action sequence somehow...

Looking forward to your valuable input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continuously populate the screen with bubbles you can use the `update:` method of your `SKScene`. Here is how to do it.

First, add a property that will store a date when you last added a bubble.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastBubbleCreationDate;
```

Then, change your `update:` method to:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    // Create new bubble every 5s.
    if (ABS([_lastBubbleCreationDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) > 5)
    {
        [self createBubbleNode];
    }
}
```

Finally, in your `createBubbleNode` method you have to store the time when you created last bubble:

```
-(void)createBubbleNode
{
    // Your code here

    // Set the date to now.
    _lastBubbleCreationDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

You also need to call `createBubbleNode` to set the initial value of the `_lastBubbleCreationDate`. You can do this in `didMoveToView:` method. Just add this method to your scene implementation:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{    
    // Creates first bubble and sets the initial value of the _lastBubbleCreationDate
    [self createBubbleNode];
}
```

In next levels you can just change the `5s` value to create bubbles more often which will make the game more difficult.